# What is mipmap in opengl?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I cant understand exactly what and OpenGL 'Mipmap' is?

where & How it could be used?

also, explain what are the following constans? How are they employed?

GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,
GL10.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST
GL10.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR
GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S
GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T
GL10.GL_REPEAT

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap

Answer (score 1):

Definition from https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.1/glspec1.1/node84.html

"A mipmap is an ordered set of arrays representing the same image; each array has a resolution lower than the previous one."

In fact you provide same image in different resolutions, so that openGL picks up the one which suits most.

There is a number of online tutorials regarding mipmapping.